# Solution of a given equation.

Tags: fundamental-solution

We need to solve that following equation for $x$ , where , $0<x<1$ ,

$(1-x)^{20}+20x(1-x)^{19}=0.025$ ,

The solution says , we need to use the "iterative methods" to find the value of this $x$ ,

Now my question is , since , $0<x<1$ , can't we just write $(1-x)^{20} \approx (1-20x)$ ??

On applying this to the main equation :

$(1-19x)(1+19x)=0.025$ , => $1-19x^{2}=0.025$ , which gives $x\approx 0.051$

Isn't this the correct approach ? 
As the given solution is $x=0.249$ ..

Comment: What kind of iterative methods did you learn up to now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do this. The approximation you mention is only true for very small $x$ (compared to $1$), so $x <<1$. If we take $x$ to be close to one, it is easy to see that $(1-x)^{20}$ is small and positive, while $1-20 x$ is negative and close to $-19$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are supposed to use an iterative method, let me suppose that you heard about Newton method : starting from guess $x_0$, the method will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ So, let us consider $$f(x)=(1-x)^{20}+20x(1-x)^{19}-0.025$$ After simplification, the derivative is $$f'(x)=-380 (1-x)^{18} x$$ which immediately shows a problem if we start at $x_0=0$.

So, we need another starting point. Even if, as already said in answers and comments, what you used is not very good, at least it gives a number. So, let us try using $x_0=0.05$. Newton method will generate the following estimates $$x_1=0.144187$$ $$x_2=0.195074$$ $$x_3=0.229416$$ $$x_4=0.245540$$ $$x_5=0.248634$$ $$x_6=0.248733$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

**Edit**

Let me point out that, in almost the same spirit as in your attempt, using the binomial expansion and stopping at the first terms, you would have found $$f(x)=\frac{39}{40}-190 x^2+\cdots$$ from which a "solution" $$x_0=\frac{1}{20}\sqrt{\frac{39}{19}}\approx 0.072$$ which would have been a little better as a starting point for the iterative process.

Comment: Newton method seems best way to approach to this question IMO.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz. I would say that Newton method (or higher orders methods such as Halley or Householder) are the best ways to solve nonlinear equations provided a reasonable guess (and a few other conditions).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a correct expansion. If you expand your expression properly you get $-361x^2$. But even this is not the correct second order approximation

If you factor as $(1-x)^{19}(1+19x)$ and regard $x$ as small, you get the binomial expansion

$$\left(1-19x+\frac {19\cdot 18}2 x^2-\frac {19\cdot 18 \cdot 17}6 x^3+\dots\right)\left (1+19x\right)$$

And the term in $x^2$ is $(19\cdot9-19^2)x^2=-190x^2$ taking both contributions. This doesn't help the accuracy - others have commented on why this is unlikely with $x$ relatively large - you need more terms of the expansion and a way of extimating the error (crudely look at the size of the first term you've dropped - certainly if that is large, the approximation is likely to be poor).

Answer (score 0):

$(1-x)^{20} \approx (1-20x)$ is only true for very small values of $x$, not for values on $(0,1)$. For example:

$$(1-0.5)^{20} = 9.5\cdot 10^{-7}$$

and

$$1-20\cdot 0.5 = -9$$

so the numbers are nowhere near close.